# Solving equation using excel-vba, If condition seems to work differently

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to solve an equation using excel-vba,

**Equation:**
xy = 5(x+y)

I use the below vba code to determine the values of `x` and `y` and print it in cell `A1`

```
Sub equation()
Dim x As Long, y As Long
For x = 1 To 9
For y = 1 To 9
    If ((x * y) = (5 * (x + y))) Then
        Range("A1") = x & "," & y
    End If
Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

However this code is not working. I guess I am missing something in the `IF` condition.

I tried the below and this works perfectly,

```
Sub equation()
Dim x As Long, y As Long
For x = 1 To 9
For y = 1 To 9
    If 5 * (x + y) = 45 Then
        Range("A1") = x & "," & y
    End If
Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

I even tried with 2 `temp` variables, but doesn't works,

```
Sub equation()
Dim x As Long, y As Long, temp1 As Long, temp2 As Long
For x = 1 To 9
For y = 1 To 9
    temp1 = x * y
    temp2 = 5 * (x + y)
    If temp1 = temp2 Then
        Range("A1") = x & "," & y
    End If
Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with the `IF` condition.

Comment: @pnuts my bad.. I got it now. Thanks !!

Comment: @pnuts The funnier part of the puzzle equation is, the xy is not x*y, but (x*10)+y .. Now i got what tricked me and my coding skills :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

xy = 5(x+y)
xy = 5x+5y
xy-5y = 5x
y(x-5) = 5x
y = 5x/(x-5)

Then just plug in values for *x* and solve for *y*

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    For x = 6 To 13
        y = 5 * x / (x - 5)
        Cells(x, 1) = x
        Cells(x, 2) = y
    Next x
End Sub
```

[image]

Pick any values for *x*, just avoid `x = 5`.
Declare `y` as **Double** if you require the fractional part:

[image]

Comment: @GowthamShiva  There is nothing wrong with the **IF()**.  Because you are stepping through a grid of **integers** there may be no values in the grid that work.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you !!